# If $A+B+C=\pi$, prove: $\cos(B+2C)+\cos(C+2A)+\cos(A+2B)=1-4\cos\frac {B-C}{2}\;\cos\frac {C-A}{2}\;\cos\frac {A-B}{2}$

Tags: trigonometry

> If $A+B+C=\pi$, prove that:
>   $$\cos(B+2C)+\cos(C+2A)+\cos(A+2B)=1-4\cos\frac {B-C}{2}\;\cos\frac {C-A}{2}\;\cos\frac {A-B}{2}$$

My Attempt:

Here, $A+B+C=\pi$

Now,
$$\begin{align}
LHS &=\cos(B+2C)+\cos(C+2A)+\cos(A+2B) \\
&=\cos(B+C+C)+\cos(C+A+A)+\cos(A+B+B) \\
&=\cos(\pi-(A-C))+\cos(\pi-(B-A))+\cos(\pi-(C-B)) \\
&=-\cos(A-C)-\cos(B-A)-\cos(C-B)
\end{align}$$

Please help to continue from here.

Comment: Certainly try: $\cos (A-C)=2\cos^2\frac{A-C}{2}-1$.

Comment: Maybe try drawing a picture of a triangle with angles $A,B,C$ and seeing if you can gain some intuition from that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $C-A=2x,B-C=2y,A-B=2z\implies2(x+y+z)=0$

$$F=\cos2x+\cos2y+\cos2z=2\cos(x+y)\cos(x-y)+2\cos^2z-1$$

Now as $\cos(x+y)=\cos(-z)=\cos z,$

$$F=2\cos z\cos(x-y)+2\cos z\cdot\cos(x+y)-1$$
$$=2\cos z\{\cos(x+y)+\cos(x-y)\}-1=2\cos z\{2\cos x\cos y\}-1=?$$

Comment: How is $cos(x+y)=cosz$?

Comment: @user354073,  $$x+y=-z\implies\cos(x+y)=\cos(-z)=?$$

Comment: And how is LHS=RHS? I could not get that. Please clarify.

Comment: @user354073, Replace the values of $x,y,z$

Comment: With that, I got:
$$4cos\frac {C-A}{2}.cos\frac {B-C}{2}.cos\frac {A-B}{2} -1$$?

Comment: @user354073, LHS $$=-\cos(A-C)-\cos(B-C)-\cos(C-B)$$  Use $\cos(-u)=+\cos u$

Answer (score 1):

For the RHS, you can use a known formula for the product of three cosines (see eg. [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formelsammlung_Trigonometrie#Additionstheoreme)):

$\cos x \; \cos y \; \cos z = \frac{1}{4} \Big(\cos (x+y-z) + \cos (y+z-x) + \cos (z+x-y) + \cos (x+y+z)\Big)$

Considering your RHS, you set $x = \frac{B-C}{2}$,  $y = \frac{C-A}{2}$,  $z = \frac{A-B}{2}$,    and plug it into the formula. Then, for example, 
$x+y-z = B-A$, likewise the other arguments.

This gives immediately the form you arrived at,
$-\cos(A-C)-\cos(B-A)-\cos(C-B)$.

Comment: Andreas,  I.could not understand. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I added more steps in the answer.